# The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. in flutter using dart

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error: `The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.`

I'm developing a e-commerce app using flutter and android studio. How can I fix this error?

[This is the youtube link for the project](https://youtu.be/XBKzpTz65Io)

[This is the github link for the source code](https://github.com/abuanwar072/E-commerce-App-UI-Flutter)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Xuo.png)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/models/Product.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/screens/details/details_screen.dart';
import 'categorries.dart';
import 'item_card.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
          child: Text(
            "Women",
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .headline5
                ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        Categories(),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
            child: GridView.builder(
                itemCount: products.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
                  crossAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemCard(
                      product: products[index],
                      press: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                              product: products[index],
                            ),
                          )),
                    )),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its most probably the case of mismatch in Flutter versions

Comment: Can you include your flutter version and how you;ve define `ItemCard`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the Flutter version. Update the Flutter SDK, download the project from GitHub again and run it.

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal upvote the answer and mark it as accepted to show the solution to your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

Below `class Body …` and above `@override` add these lines:

```
const Body({
Key? Key,
}) : super(key: key);
```

`Key` is a default thing you should pass to all `Stateless` and `Stateful` Flutter widgets.

Answer (score 0):

```
///Changed Key to "Key?"    
const ItemCard({
        Key? key,
        this.product,
        this.press,
      }) : super(key: key);

///Changed Key to "Key?"
const DetailsScreen({Key? key, 
this.product}) : super(key: key);
```

Above mentioned changes works for me.